# Delphi Web Script: How to call a Script Function from Delphi Code within an Execution Context?

Tags: delphi, dwscript

Imaging this scripting code:

```
procedure A;
begin
  CallToDelphi;
end;

procedure B;
begin
  // do something
end;
```

I have exposed the procedure "CallToDelphi" to the script. So when it is called, I'm back from script in my Delphi code. I now want to call the script procedure "B" from my Delphi Code.
I think is must be hidden in the IdwsProgramExecution-Context. But I didn't found anything yet. I'm looking for a something like that:

```
procedure CallToDelphi;
begin
  Exec.Invoke('B', []); // Exec is IdwsProgramExecution
end;
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably the IInfo interface which can be used as

```
Exec.Info.Func['B'].Call([])
```

There are some more samples in http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/wiki/FirstSteps (scroll down to functions), and also some usage code in the unit tests (UdwsUnitTests notably, see the CallFunc method).

The IInfo serves Delphi-side as the primary way to query RTTI, invoke functions, get/set variables directly, instantiate script-side objects, etc. Most of the sample code for it is currently in the unit tests though.

Comment: Thank you. I already browsed through the unit tests, but didn't find it. Thanks for your guidance. Now it's clear. This is exactly what I was looking for.